# How do I Select from two tables using Two WHERE Conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application that has a referral system where users can use their `user_id` to refer another user. All users are on the same table. The referrals table stores the `user_id` for the referrer and for the referred.

Users Table:
[image]

Referrals Table:
[image]

I want to query the names of both users (referrer and referred) from the user's table using their `user_id` that is populated in the referrals table.

Expected Result:
[image]

Comment: A JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them. I want to combine two columns (names), based on no related value

Comment: Can you post some short example of table what you have and what output you expect?

Comment: You can join "users" table 2 times just use alias to seprate joins and will get name of the referrer and for the referred both

Comment: I have edited the question to include a basic structure of the tables and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t2.name as  referrer_name,t3.name as  referred_name
from REFERRALS_TABLE t1
left join USER_TABLE t2 ON t1.referrer=t2.user_id
left join USER_TABLE t3 ON t1.referred=t3.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I method is to join the User_table twice -

```
SELECT U1.name referrers_name, U2.name referred_name
FROM Referrals R
JOIN Users U1 ON R.referrer = U1.user_id
JOIN Users U2 ON R.referrd = U1.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You use sql UNION if get two table data and multiple where clouse.

```
SELECT * FROM oauth_clients WHERE user_id=2
UNION
SELECT * FROM photos where gallery_id=12
```